# How could I make a directory and navigate to the directory by only typing the name of the directory once using bash?

Tags: bash

How would I accomplish the equivalent of:

```
> mkdir yo; cd yo;
```

by only typing the name of the directory, `yo`, once?

Comment: `alias yo='mkdir yo; cd yo'`

Comment: BTW, inasmuch as this is a question about *using* the shell more than it is a question about writing scripts for interpretation by the shell, you might consider [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for similar questions in the future.